# Facebook ads API creative creation fails with 503

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I've been creating adsets, ads and creatives with FB ads API for a long time now, more precisely using the [python SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk). For most of my campaign, I always encounter a 503 error at some point, when creating creatives by batch.

When trying to create 5 creatives, 4 out of 5 are successfully created, and for one of them (the 4th one in this case) I get the following error:

```
{"error":
    {"message": "Service temporarily unavailable",
     "type":"FacebookApiException",
    "is_transient":false,
    "code":2,
    "error_subcode":1487172,
    "error_user_title":"Could not save creative",
    "error_user_msg":"Could not save creative"
}
```

I already [created an issue on the SDK repo](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/issues/61) but I really think it's a problem of the API itself. Any idea? Are there any rate limitations? I couldn't find any documentation nor similar issue.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The error subcode 1487172 is listed on the [Marketing API Error Codes Facebook documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/error-reference) so it doesn't strike me as a rate limit error which is documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting.

For a batch request of 5 creatives do you always see 1 fail? Is there anything consistent between the failed creatives to suggest something wrong in the request?

You could also search the known bug list or create a new one, it does sound like this is an issue on the API side. See https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: - not always one fail. I must say that use exactly the same data for the 5 creatives
- in production environment, we have much more failure, that's why we're concerned

I'll check the known bugs thanks